# Counting the number of times a value change signs with R

Tags: r

I am very new with R but encouraged with it because I find it accessible although I am not a programmer. I am trying to get around the following issue: I need to count how many times a value change signs in a column and then sort the results by Path (The example for a table is below- Path is a factor). I can figure how to sort the data once I eventually get them but have yet to figure out the count for the number of times a + sign becomes - and a - sign becomes a + one. Any suggestion?

```
Test <- structure(list(Path = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Direction = c(-3.84089, 
-1.12258, 1.47411, -1.47329, 5.4525, 10.161)), .Names = c("Path", 
"Direction"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
head(Test)
#>   Path    Direction
#> 1    1     -3.84089
#> 2    1     -1.12258
#> 3    1      1.47411
#> 4    2     -1.47329
#> 5    2      5.4525
#> 6    2     10.161
```

Comment: use something like `foo <- Test > 0`.  then use the run length encoding function `rle`.  `length(rle(foo)$lengths))`.

Comment: Do you mean how frequently the sign changes for values for a given path?

Answer (score 13):

I think what you are looking for is

```
 sum(diff(sign(X)) != 0)
```

where `X` is the vector, in your case, `dat$Direction` which you're trying to count sign changes.

---

If you want to calculate by `Path`, you can use the `by` function, or convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table` and use the built in `by` capabilities.

### Example:

*assuming `X` is your original `data.frame`*

```
# I'm adding another row to the data, just to show that it works 
#    (ie, giving the two Path values a different number of rows)
X <- rbind(X, c(2, -5))

# convert to a data.table
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(X)

# count the number of changes, per path
DT[, changes := sum(diff(sign(Direction)) != 0), by=Path]
```

#### Edit (re comment about `factors`):

if `Direction` is a `factor`, it will need to be converted to `numeric` first. You can do this using

```
DT[, Direction := as.numeric(Direction)]
```

### Results:

```
DT

       Path Direction changes
  1:    1  -3.84089       1
  2:    1  -1.12258       1
  3:    1   1.47411       1
  4:    2  -1.47329       2
  5:    2   5.45250       2
  6:    2  10.16100       2
  7:    2  -5.00000       2
```

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thank you to all. I am still getting the following message even after converting to data.table: Error in Math.factor(Direction) : sign not meaningful for factors I have tried to re-convert the data to a data.frame with no success. What do i do wrong?

Comment: not sure why you ended up with a `factor` `Direction` (my guess is that you read it from a file and have characters in that column in addition to numbers), but a quick fix is to wrap `Direction` in `as.numeric`, i.e. use `as.numeric(Direction)` in the above answer

Comment: @Gale2, eddi is correct.  Please see the edit for the correct syntax.

Comment: If you only want to strictly count sign changes and not non-zero to zero changes then a quick and dirty way to do that is to add .0000001 to your `X`.  It, of course, assumes that that wouldn't make a value that isn't otherwise 0 into 0 or perhaps even cross signs but if that happens just add more zeros before the 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `sign` and `rle` as Justin suggests:

```
length(rle(sign(Test$Direction))[[1]])
```

**EDIT**
I may have misunderstood at first.  Maybe this is closer to what you want:

```
vals <- tail(rle(sign(Test$Direction))[[-1]], -1)
sum(vals > 0) # neg to pos
sum(vals < 0) # pos to neg
```

Comment: This is nice but I get an error message that there is an error and these do not apply to factors. Do I need to make a data.frame?

Comment: Take a look at the output of `str(Test)`.  And then look at `?factor`.

Comment: I think your first answer will be equivalent to `sum(diff(sign(X)) != 0)` if you change it to `length(rle(sign(Test$Direction))[[1]]) - 1`.